# Set Default tab as Data when clicking on table in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I set the default tab as **Data** when clicking on table in Oracle SQL Developer. Currently, I am getting **columns** as the default tab in Oracle SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

But if the data tab is active in a table, and you go to open another table, it will take the first table's place, with the data tab still active.

If the table you open goes to a new document in the desktop (first table is pinned), the columns page will be active.

We do this because querying the data can take awhile.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How can I request for this feature to the oracle sql developer team ?

Comment: you just did @SaiA :)